# Initialization of Classes in Java

Tags: java, initialization

I'm reading [section 12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) of the JLS, the first line says

*"Initialization of a class consists of executing its static initializers **and the initializers for static fields** (class variables) declared in the class. "*

What does it mean the part in bold? **Static initializers** and **initializers** are blocks like these:

```
class Foo{
    static { ... }
    { ... }
}
```

So, what is an *initializer for static fields*? It's just referring to *instructions in the RHS of a static field declaration*? Something like the call to *p()* method, to be clear?

```
class Foo{
    static int b=p();
    static int p(){
        System.out.println("ciao");
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: Note that you can also do `static final int i; static { i = 3; }`

Comment: note also that before class initialization begins, all static variables are set to default values depending on their type (like 0, null etc).

Comment: Also note that there's a hazard here which is rarely stated: It's possible to write a cycle in static initializations, where one class's statics depend on another class and the other class's statics depend on the first (perhaps A's statics need an instance of B but B uses a static-final "constant" from A). This can result in accessing statics in one of these classes before static initialization has been completed. Java will not warn you about this; it will just return the uninitialized (zero/null) value. It's the coder's responsibility to recognize the problem and refactor to break the loop.

Comment: Exactly @keshlam , something like this `public class Main {static int b=p();static int p(){return b;}}` wich, surprisingly (for me), is not an error nor an infinite loop